# Tomcat Remote Debugging (jpda)

Tags: java, tomcat, jvm, tomcat7, tomcat8

i want to enable Tomcat Remote Debugging on a special port for connecting my source and debug applications but before it i want to understand:

can we change the source code on tomcat(webapps) by JPDA port ?

Comment: What do you mean by changing *source code*? Using JDWP you can change the (binary) code of already loaded classes.

Comment: I mean the .war Contents OR files in compiled directory and jar files and OR with this port upload new jar file on web app directory

Comment: [JPDA](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jpda/architecture.html) has nothing to do with Tomcat, .war, file uploading etc.

Comment: thank you very much @apangin